# Center an image veritcally and horizontally, translate on iPhone

Tags: html, css

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  /*
  Nope =(
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  */

  /* 
  Yep!
  */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /*
  Not even necessary really. 
  e.g. Height could be left out!
  */
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

This works fine in the web browser. However on mobile tranforsm doesn't seem to be supported. What's a simple solution that works?

My HTML:

```
<div id="responsive-with-backgroundimg">
<img src="" class="center">
</div>
```

Comment: have u tried margin:auto

Comment: of course `transform` is supported on mobile, that is a ridicules claim.  http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 2):

You [need the `-webkit-` prefix](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In different browsers you have to work with prefixing your css
this should look like this:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

You might as well should consider using flex

Answer (score -1):

at the moment this is my favorite way to center an image:

```
img.center {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 top: -9999px;
 right: -9999px;
 bottom: -9999px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a hack than a solution

Comment: The question is, if it's supported in every browser...
I'm pretty sure you can't test that.

Comment: ever heard of browserstack? it works in ie8+, ff8+, opera 12+ and thats all i bothered to test

Comment: Guess it works... though if you want to be professional about your work, you should consider changing to a more universal approach, no offense.